# How to update flex item size based on animation that does transform: scaleX on child of this flex item

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, css-animations

Thats my HTML:

```
<div id="layout">
    <div id="sidebar" #sidebar>
        <div id="sidebar-elements" #sidebarElements>
            <div id="group-conversations-bar">
                <app-group-conversation *ngFor="let groupConv of groupConversations" [groupConversation]="groupConv" class="group-avatar">
                </app-group-conversation>
            </div>

            <div id="hello-bar">
                <div id="logo"></div>

                <div id="private-conversations-bar">
                    <app-private-conversation *ngFor="let privateConv of privateConversations" [privateConversation]="privateConv">
                    </app-private-conversation>
                </div>

                <div id="welcome-message">
                    Hi,&nbsp;Nice human
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar-collapser" class="gg-arrow-right-r" (click)="collapseSidebar()" #collapser></div>
    </div>
    <div id="chat">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

And on `sidebar-collapser` click I want to collapse the `sidebar-elements` using `scaleX`, and also the parent `sidebar` size should change to be as smallest as possible (and at the end width should be 0). That's the CSS (I think the most necessary piece of it):

```
#layout {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #1B1C1E;
  align-items: stretch;
  font-size: 1vw;
}

#sidebar {
  flex: 1 0 22%;
  background-color: aqua;
  position: relative;
  font-size: inherit;
}

#sidebar-elements {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#group-conversations-bar {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: calc(3px + .2em);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: auto;
  gap: calc(3px + .2em);
}

#hello-bar {
  flex: 1 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

#sidebar-collapser {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  background-color: #6200ea;
}

#chat {
  flex: 1 1 78%;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

and the `collapseSidebar` method (not complete, only one-way operation):

```
  collapseSidebar() {
    this.sidebarElements.nativeElement.style.transformOrigin = 'left'
    let isDisplayed = this.sidebarElements.nativeElement.style.display !== 'none'
    if (isDisplayed) {
      this.sidebarElements.nativeElement.animate(this.sidebarElementsCollapsAnim, this.sidebarElementsCollapsAnimSettings)
      this.collapser.nativeElement.animate(this.rotateCollapserAnim, this.rotateCollapserAnimSettings)
    }
```

and animation responsible for collapsing the `sidebar-elements`, which is used by above method:

```
 sidebarElementsCollapsAnim: Keyframe[] = [
    { transform: 'scaleX(1)' },
    { transform: 'scaleX(0)' }
  ]

  sidebarElementsCollapsAnimSettings: KeyframeAnimationOptions = {
    duration: 1000,
    fill: 'both',
    easing: 'linear'
  }
```

I tried manipulating the `flex` and `width` property of `sidebar` before starting the animation, but nothing what I tried works. With the code I provided, the `sidebar-elements` are transformed properly, but the parent size doesnt change.

So how can I resize the flex item that has child which is transformed by `scaleX`, to be as smallest as possible (width equal to width of child being transformed), and the end to have width equal to 0?